# How to change page when item is selected in wicket dropDownBox

Tags: java, wicket

In dropdownBox I have list of pages. When I chose one I want to go to that page.

How should I implement it ? I am supposed to add this code but I don't know what should I do **onUpdate**. I didn't find any method to change the page

```
new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior() {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Exception when I try first response:

```
29 Jun 2012 10:07:01,772 ERROR [1215661@qtp-28488784-5] org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper : Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at cz.isvs.reg.rob.monitor.web.BasePage$1 {event='onchange'} on component [DropDownChoice [Component id = vyjimkyPage]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:270)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:784)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:255)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:244)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:260)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to set model object on null model of component: vyjimkyPage
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3054)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1498)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1059)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.java:154)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:184)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:369)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target){
   target.prependJavaScript("window.location.href='"+urlFor(new YourPage())+'");
  }
```

It will change the browser's url and thus redirect.

Comment: The problem is in the model of your dropdownchoice, it does not exists. If the selected value is not important, you can replace your `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` with a `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` otherwise, set a model to your DropdownChoice when you create it.

Answer (score 0):

*AbstractSingleSelectChoice* components (the parent of *DropDownChoice*) cannot use the *AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior*. The class javadoc refers you to the *AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior*:

> NOTE: This behavior does not work on Choices or Groups use the AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior for that.

It's also true that you should be using a model if you use a AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior as it will perform field conversion, validation, and push to the model... Keep in mind that id you don't care about the value, you can simply provide an empty model that you never read later.

Finally, in Wicket, you can do a redirect that will update the browser's url by throwing a *RedirectException* (a runtime exception that expects a *Page* class and optional *PageParameters*) or a *RedirectToUrlException* which expects a string url:

```
throw new RedirectToUrlException("http://www.supercoolwebsite.com/supercoolexternalpage");
```

vs

```
throw new RedirectException(SuperCoolWicketPage.class);
```